# Invalid countryId error since update 2.4.3 -> 2.4.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.4.4

Since I updated a Magento 2 instance from version 2.4.3 to 2.4.4, I get the error message that the countryId "DE" is invalid when checking out with the payment methods PayPal and credit card payment.
Does anyone have a tip for me where the error comes from and how I can fix it?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

<strike>After I did a *composer update*, the problem fortunately resolved.</strike>
Unfortunately, I still don't have a solution for the problem, but I can narrow it down in the meantime: the behavior occurs since the update and is related to the fact that the store website uses the list of Allowed Countries. If I undo the restriction to countries and set it to "System value", the error does not occur. It is also interesting that the error only occurs when the user is logged in; there is no error message for guest users. So it must be a comparison of the countries from the list of Allowed countries with the country from the form dropdown, which is only executed when the user is logged in. Since the form value of the country_id dropdown is always the same - regardless of whether the user is logged in or not - I suspect that the values from the list of Allowed countries differ.
How can this bug be fixed?